# Forcing user logout if account is expired

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to force the user to logout if his account is expired. I'm using Asp.Net MVC core 3, And here one of the solution I got.

I added new class under Services "ValidateAsync".

```
public class ValidateAsync
    {
        public static async Task ValidatingAsync(CookieValidatePrincipalContext context)
        {
            context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));
            var claimsIdentity = context.Principal.Identity as ClaimsIdentity;
            if (claimsIdentity?.Claims == null || !claimsIdentity.Claims.Any())
            {
                await RejectPrincipal();
                return;
            }
            UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            var user = await userManager.FindByNameAsync(context.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier));
            if (user == null || user.SecurityStamp != context.Principal.FindFirst(new ClaimsIdentityOptions().SecurityStampClaimType)?.Value)
            {
                await RejectPrincipal();
                return;
            }
            async Task RejectPrincipal()
            {
                context.RejectPrincipal();
                await context.HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            }
        }
    }
```

In Startup class I added inside 'ConfigureServices' method:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
{
    
    options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync
    };
}).Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

And in here I have a background process where it set the user expired, and at the same I want to force him to logout if he is logged in after being expired.

```
public async Task SetExpired()
    {
        foreach(var item in _db.Institution)
        {
            if (item.SubscriptionEndDate != null)
            {
                if (item.SubscriptionEndDate == DateTime.Today) 
                {
                    item.Status = SD.StatusExpired;

                  //Here I want to check if the user is logged in, then force logout should be done.     
                  Guid securityStamp = Guid.NewGuid();
                  item.SecurityStamp = securityStamp;

                }
            }
        }
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
```

I don't know if my approach should work as expected or not. But ValidateAsync in startup class show the following error:

CS0119: 'ValidateAsync' is a type, which is not valid in the giving context.

please any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A small misuse. Change

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync
};
```

to

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
{
    OnValidatePrincipal = ValidateAsync.ValidatingAsync
};
```